# Confusing of "Access Violation "

Tags: c++, c++builder

I don't Understand with this case but this is really really important for me, Please Help me...

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button4Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    String masuk, keluar, kosong;
    int i, x, j, n = 0;

    masuk = Edit2->Text;
    keluar = masuk;
    kosong = " ";
    n = 0;
    x = 0;

mulai:
    i = 1;
    j = 0;
    j = j + n;
    i = i + j;
    if (masuk[i] == 'a')
    {
        keluar[i] = 't';
    }
    else if (masuk[i] == 't')
    {
        keluar[i] = 'a';
    }
    else if (masuk[i] == 'c')
    {
        keluar[i] = 'g';
    }
    else if (masuk[i] == 'g')
    {
        keluar[i] = 'c';
    }
    else
    {
        Application->MessageBoxA("Masukan Anda Salah", "Peringatan", MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING);
        keluar = kosong;
        goto end;
    }
    n = n + 1;
    if (i < 10)
        goto mulai;
    else
        goto end;

end:
    Memo1->Text = keluar;
}
```

if I make masukan more than 10 (i<10 (10 as default value)), it is ok but if it less than 10, it will make message exception Class EAccessViolation..

Comment: Why the `goto`s instead of a proper loop?

Comment: Access Violation usually means your attempting to access memory not available to the current memory block, i.e. you went out of bounds of your array (the string).  Also, don't use goto.

Comment: Looks like something DNA/RNA related. I'm assuming a,t,g,c are adenosine, guanine, thymine and cytosine.

Comment: If anyone's wondering the language for the variable names appears to be Indonesian.

Comment: I've ever try that way, but my proggram cannot read looping.. when I put for (int i=0; i<10; i++), my program show AccessViolation. that's why I used "goto"

Answer (score 1):

Taking a shot in the dark, but I think what you're actually trying to do might be this. I'm assuming that you're taking a single string of 10 characters which represents one half of a genome and you're generating another string of the pair values.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button4Click(TObject *Sender)
{
  String masuk, keluar;
  masuk = Edit2->Text;
  keluar = masuk;

  char kosong = ' ';

  for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    switch(masuk[i]) {
      case 'a':
        keluar[i] = 't';
        break;
      case 't':
        keluar[i] = 'a';
        break;
      case 'c':
        keluar[i] = 'g';
        break;
      case 'g':
        keluar[i] = 'c';
        break;
      default:
        Application->MessageBoxA("Masukan Anda Salah", "Peringatan", MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING);
        keluar[i] = kosong;
        break;
  }
  Memo1->Text = keluar;
}
```

Comment: I've ever try that way, but my proggram cannot read looping..
when I put for (int i=0; i<10; i++), my program show AccessViolation.
that's why I used "goto"..